# Can jQuery plugins pass the AirBnB Javascript style guide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, eslint

I have a simple jQuery Plugin written as so:

```js
'use strict';

(function ($) {
  $.fn.example = function () {
    $('#test').html('example');
  };
}(jQuery));

$('#test').example();
```

I have also installed [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) configured with the [Airbnb JavaScript](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) style guide which I would like to use to ensure code consistency within my JavaScript.

However when I run ESLint I receive this error:

```sh
  4:3  error  Assignment to property of function parameter '$'  no-param-reassign
```

Is there a way to write this plugin and pass ESLint without excluding `no-param-reassign` in the `.eslintrc`?

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing `$` with `jQuery` ?
That should work fine.

Comment: @daveyfaherty that worked a treat thanks.